# Debugging in Hadoop - MapReduce . Mapper not being called?

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop, mapreduce, breadth-first-search

I'v been teaching myself Hadoop over the past few days and was trying to implement a basic BFS algorithms according to the information given at [this webpage](http://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Iterative+MapReduce+and+Counters#discussion). I had to do some modifications and additions to get the code compiled. I got the following error on running and even after spending hours debugging I could not solve this. Could someone help me with this?

ERROR:

```
15/05/11 03:04:20 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local934121164_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/05/11 03:04:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local934121164_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/05/11 03:04:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
```

Which should not happen as in the mapper as well as the reducer I'm following the same key , value types as you can see below. The only thing which I think is happning here is that my mapper class is not being used and instead the default one is used (which emits **LongWritable** key). I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

**SearchMapper.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
public class SearchMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

    // Types of the input key, input value and the Context object through which 
    // the Mapper communicates with the Hadoop framework
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context, Node inNode)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // For each GRAY node, emit each of the adjacent nodes as a new node
        // (also GRAY) if the adjacent node is already processed
        // and colored BLACK, the reducer retains the color BLACK
        // Note that the mapper is not differentiating between BLACK GREY AND WHITE

        if (inNode.getColor() == Node.Color.GRAY) {
            for (String neighbor : inNode.getEdges()) { 
                Node adjacentNode = new Node();

                // Remember that the current node only has the value the id 
                // of its neighbour, and not the object itself. Therefore at 
                // this stage there is no way of knowing and assigning any of
                // its other properties. Also remember that the reducer is doing
                // the 'clean up' task and not the mapper.
                adjacentNode.setId(neighbor); 
                adjacentNode.setDistance(inNode.getDistance() + 1);
                adjacentNode.setColor(Node.Color.GRAY);
                adjacentNode.setParent(inNode.getId());
                context.write(new Text(adjacentNode.getId()), adjacentNode.getNodeInfo()); // Get nodeinfo returns a Text Object
            }
            inNode.setColor(Node.Color.BLACK);
        }
        // Emit the input node, other wise the BLACK color change(if it happens)
        // Wont be persistent 
        context.write(new Text(inNode.getId()), inNode.getNodeInfo());

    }
}
```

**SearchReducer.java**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SearchReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    // Types of the input key, the values associated with the key, the Context object for Reducers communication
    // with the Hadoop framework and the node whose information has to be output
    // the return type is a Node
    public Node reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context, Node outNode)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // set the node id as the key
        outNode.setId(key.toString());

        // TODO : (huh?) Since the values are of the type Iterable, iterate through the values associated with the key
        // for all the values corresponding to a particular node id

        for (Text value : values) {

            Node inNode = new Node(key.toString() + "\t" + value.toString());

            // Emit one node after combining all the mapper outputs

            // Only one node(the original) will have a non-null adjascency list
            if (inNode.getEdges().size() > 0) {
                outNode.setEdges(inNode.getEdges());
            }

            // Save the minimum distance and parent
            if (inNode.getDistance() < outNode.getDistance()) {
                outNode.setDistance(inNode.getDistance());
                outNode.setParent(inNode.getParent());
            }

            // Save the darkest color
            if (inNode.getColor().ordinal() > outNode.getColor().ordinal()) {
                outNode.setColor(inNode.getColor());
            }        
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(outNode.getNodeInfo()));      
        return outNode;
    }
}
```

**BaseJob.java** ( a generic class the website mentioned follows which basically sets the job up)

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import java.io.IOException;

public abstract class BaseJob extends Configured implements Tool {

        protected Job setupJob(String jobName,JobInfo jobInfo) throws Exception {

        Job job = new Job(new Configuration(), jobName);
        job.setJarByClass(jobInfo.getJarByClass());

        job.setMapperClass(jobInfo.getMapperClass());
        if (jobInfo.getCombinerClass() != null)
            job.setCombinerClass(jobInfo.getCombinerClass());
        job.setReducerClass(jobInfo.getReducerClass());

        // TODO : set number of reducers as required
        job.setNumReduceTasks(3);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(jobInfo.getOutputKeyClass());
        job.setOutputValueClass(jobInfo.getOutputValueClass());
       /*
        job.setJarByClass(SSSPJob.class);
        job.setMapperClass(SearchMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(SearchReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(3);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);*/
        return job;
    }

   // Implement an abstract class for JobInfo object
    protected abstract class JobInfo {
        public abstract Class<?> getJarByClass();
        public abstract Class<? extends Mapper> getMapperClass();
        public abstract Class<? extends Reducer> getCombinerClass();
        public abstract Class<? extends Reducer> getReducerClass();
        public abstract Class<?> getOutputKeyClass();
        public abstract Class<?> getOutputValueClass();

    }
}
```

**SSSPJob.java** (the driver)

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counters;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class SSSPJob extends BaseJob {
    // method to set the configuration for the job and the mapper and the reducer classes
    private Job getJobConf(String[] args) 
        throws Exception {

    // Defining the abstract class objects
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo() {
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Reducer> getCombinerClass() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getJarByClass() {
                return SSSPJob.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Mapper> getMapperClass() {
                return SearchMapper.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getOutputKeyClass() {
                return Text.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<?> getOutputValueClass() {
                return Text.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Class<? extends Reducer> getReducerClass() {
                return SearchReducer.class;
            }
        };

        return setupJob("ssspjob", jobInfo);

    }

    // the driver to execute the job and invoke the map/reduce functions

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int iterationCount = 0; 
        Job job;
        // No of grey nodes
        long terminationValue = 1;

        while( terminationValue >0){
            job = getJobConf(args); 
            String input, output;

            // Setting the input file and output file for each iteration
            // During the first time the user-specified file will be the
            // input whereas for the subsequent iterations
            // the output of the previous iteration will be the input
            // NOTE: Please be clear of how the input output files are set
            //       before proceding.

            // for the first iteration the input will be the first input argument
            if (iterationCount == 0) 
                input = args[0];
            else
                // for the remaining iterations, the input will be the output of the previous iteration
                input = args[1] + iterationCount;

            output = args[1] + (iterationCount + 1);

            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(input));
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output));

            job.waitForCompletion(true); 

            Counters jobCntrs = job.getCounters();
            terminationValue = jobCntrs.findCounter(MoreIterations.numberOfIterations).getValue();
            // if the counter's value is incremented in the reducer(s), then there are more
            // GRAY nodes to process implying that the iteration has to be continued.
            iterationCount++;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new SSSPJob(), args);
        if(args.length != 2){
            System.err.println("Usage: <in> <output name> ");
            System.exit(1);
            System.out.println("Huh?");
        }
        System.exit(res);
    }

}
```

And furthermore, Im not sure how debugging is done on hadoop. All my debug print statements seems not to have any effect and I suspect the hadoop framework writes the log messages to some other place or file.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The key in the MR job should implement WritableComparable, and value should implement Writable. I think your mapper code is using "Object" type of instance. 
Just add the @Override annotation before your map and reduce methods so that they will show the errors.
Otherwise, you dont see any errors, but since the signature doesnt match, the default IdentityMapper is being called and hence the error.
If you are processing a text file, the key for map method should be LongWritable, if you want to use a custom key, it should implement WritableComparable.

Comment: Thank you, I can see the error on adding @ Override. Can you point me to a resource which explains WHY and how this is required. Further can I change the signature of the map method to include an extra parameter as shown above if I implement the writable comparable interface ?